# Setting loop condition

Tags: python, loops

New to programming, for practice I'm attempting to program the I-Ching oracle.
I'm getting the output I want, but only by copying this code block into my program 6 times.

Is there a loop condition I can set to make this more concise?

I've read the docs and tuts on looping but haven't seen how it could be applied in this context.

```
import random 

oracle = random.randint(6,9)

if oracle == 6:
   print "__ __~"
elif oracle == 7:
 print "_____"
elif oracle == 8:
 print "__ __"
elif oracle == 9:
 print "_____~"   (X6)
```

=>
this is the output I am getting:

```
_____
__ __
__ __~
_____
_____~
__ __
```

Comment: So you want to generate 6 random numbers b/w 6-9 and then print output based on each ?

Comment: What is the output you're looking for, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a while loop like this:

```
import random 

counter = 0

while counter < 6:
    oracle = random.randint(6,9)

    if oracle == 6:
       print "__ __~"
    elif oracle == 7:
       print "_____"
    elif oracle == 8:
       print "__ __"
    elif oracle == 9:
       print "_____~"

    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Do note that your probability distribution is wrong.

To do an I Ching reading you are supposed to flip 3 fair coins and sum 2 points for each tail and 3 points for each head:

```
Coin1  Coin2  Coin3  Points
t      t      t      6
t      t      h      7
t      h      t      7
t      h      h      8
h      t      t      7
h      t      h      8
h      h      t      8
h      h      h      9
```

You can see that there are 3 ways to sum to 7 or 8 but only one way to sum to 6 or 9; thus the distribution should be 6: 12.5%, 7: 37.5%, 8: 37.5%, 9: 12.5%. `randint` gives a uniform distribution, ie 25% each.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
from random import randint

xyin  = "__ __~"
yang  = "_____"
yin   = "__ __"
xyang = "_____~"

three_coins = [ xyin, yang, yang, yin, yang, yin, yin, xyang ]

def cast():
    return three_coins[randint(0, 7)]

def hexagram():
    return '\n'.join(cast() for i in range(6))

print hexagram()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop construct like this:

```
import random 

for x in range(6):  # Loop 6 times
    oracle = random.randint(6,9)
    if oracle == 6:
       print "__ __~"
    elif oracle == 7:
       print "_____"
    elif oracle == 8:
       print "__ __"
    elif oracle == 9:
       print "_____~"   (X6)
```

More on range function from `help(range)`:

> range(...)
>       range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers
>
> ```
> Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
> range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
> ```

---

You can also use a `while` construct for achieving the same effect.

```
start = 0
stop = 6
while start < stop:
    #Your code-block here
    start = start+1
```

Comment: excellent, thank you-  i much appreciate the 2 different approaches

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import random 

for n in range(6):
  oracle = random.randint(6,9)
  if oracle == 6:
    print "__ __~"
  elif oracle == 7:
    print "_____"
  elif oracle == 8:
    print "__ __"
  elif oracle == 9:
    print "_____~"
```

Ouput:

```
__ __
__ __~
_____~
__ __~
_____~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace that stack of `if` and `elif` with a dictionary and the loop with a list comprehension and reduce this to only a few lines

```
d = {6: "__ __~", 7: "_____" , 8: "__ __" , 9: "_____~",}
print '\n'.join([d[random.randint(6, 9)] for j in range(6)])
```

Comment: @Jessemon The readability may be debatable.  I think using dictionaries as switch statements is far _more_ readable than 15+ lines of boiler plate if statements.